# How to run other main class during runtome and get it's console output?

Tags: java, jar, runtime

I have a list of jars that contains jar with needed main-class.
I try to run it main class:

```
public static void runCommandlineMain(String classPathFile, String args[]) throws Exception{
    URL[] urls = getJarUrls(classPathFile);
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass("liquibase.commandline.Main");
    Method main = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    main.invoke(null, new Object[]{args});
}
```

But after run I've follow:

```
Process finished with exit code -1
```

and nothing more.
How can i resolve it? And how to get console out put from this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't quite get your first question.

But, to answer your second question: "How do you get console output"

try the StreamGobbler [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what the question is about too, but according to the posted snipped, the process which should have the output captured just runs in a different thread. In this scenario you should be able to just redirect the Sytem.out (or System.err respectively) stream.

Call

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(your-output-stream));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(your-output-stream));
```

before invoking the Main class and its output should get redirected to your custom OutputStream.